# How to Save Excel without an user prompt to save the file?

Tags: excel, vbscript, save

Hi I wrote some code using VBScript on Excel sheet as below. Now everytime when the Script is done its processing it is prompting the user to `Save` it.But I don't want this,rather I want it to save it automatically without prompt.

**CODE**

```
    Option Explicit

    Dim objExcel1,strPathExcel1,objSheet1,objSheet5

    Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")'Object for Condition Dump
    strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\GE_Wing_To_Wing_Report.xlsx"
    objExcel1.Workbooks.Open strPathExcel1
    Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set objSheet5 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(5)

    '=====================================================================================
    'Here Bad sheet will be copied by the data from First sheet master data sheet
    '=====================================================================================
       ParentPIDFromMasterSheet objSheet1,objSheet5

    '=====================================================================================
    'Here Bad sheet will be copied by the data from First sheet master data sheet
    '=====================================================================================
       BadDataSelectionDel objSheet5

    '=======================
    objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strPathExcel1
    objExcel1.Workbooks.close
    objExcel1.Application.Quit
    '======================
```

Comment: Related: [Open an Excel file and save as .XLS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17464698/3357935)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UNTESTED (Try this)**

You need to set your workbook and then close it after saving it. Also it is a good practice to clean up your objects at the end of your code after use. :)

```
Option Explicit

Dim objExcel1, objWB, strPathExcel1, objSheet1, objSheet5

Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'Object for Condition Dump
strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\GE_Wing_To_Wing_Report.xlsx"
Set objWB = objExcel1.Workbooks.Open(strPathExcel1)
Set objSheet1 = objWB.Worksheets(1)
Set objSheet5 = objWB.Worksheets(5)

'=====================================================================================
'Here Bad sheet will be copied by the data from First sheet master data sheet
'=====================================================================================
   ParentPIDFromMasterSheet objSheet1, objSheet5

'=====================================================================================
'Here Bad sheet will be copied by the data from First sheet master data sheet
'=====================================================================================
   BadDataSelectionDel objSheet5

'=======================
objWB.Save
objWB.Close
objExcel1.Quit

'~~> Cleanup
Set objSheet1 = Nothing
Set objSheet5 = Nothing
Set objWB = Nothing
Set objExcel1 = Nothing
'======================
```

Comment: hi Siddharth, why is it good practice to close yoru objects? what are the implications? :) #generalcuriosity

Comment: Very Good Question :) If you do a google search you will get your answer. This has been widely covered

Comment: To save with a specific filename, you can use `objWB.SaveAs "C:\path\to\file\filename.xlsx"` (See [Open an Excel file and save as .XLS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17464698/3357935))

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add this line of code before saving your file :

```
objExcel1.Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Prevents prompts from appearing
```

I tried it and it worked.