# Open an Excel file and save as .XLS

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-office

I have the following code, I want it to open my files which are saved as .xlsx and simply save them again with the same filename but this time as a .xls file so that they are compatible with Excel 2003

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("Y:\Billing_Common\autoemail").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "xlsx" Then
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)

app.DisplayAlerts = False

wb.SaveAs "*.xls*"
wb.Close SaveChanges=True
app.Close
app.Quit

  End if

Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Next
```

Comment: It's good to see some code, but would you describe to us the problem with the solution thus far?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17464783/1630171) already pointed out, `Set fso = Nothing` and `app.Quit` belong at the end of the script (outside the loop). There are some more bugs, though.

- `wb.SaveAs "*.xls*"`

  You can't save a workbook to a wildcard name. If you want to save the workbook under its current name, just use `wb.Save`. Otherwise you'll have to use an explicit name (you should also set the filetype then):

  ```
  wb.SaveAs "new.xlsx", 51
  ```

  or

  ```
  wb.SaveAs "C:\path\to\new.xls", -4143
  ```
- `wb.Close SaveChanges=True`

  VBScript doesn't support named parameters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info)). If you want to call the `Close` method with the `SaveChanges` parameter set to `True` you have to do it like this:

  ```
  wb.Close True
  ```
- `app.Close`

  The application object doesn't have a `Close` method.

Not bugs, but things worth improving:

- `app.DisplayAlerts = False` should go before the loop starts unless you re-enable it inside the loop as well.
- I'd recommend adding a line `app.Visible = False` after you create the application object. When you have to debug your script you can simply change that value to `True` to show the application on your desktop. That helps a lot with finding bugs.

Fixed-up script:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = False
app.DisplayAlerts = False

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("Y:\Billing_Common\autoemail").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "xlsx" Then
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)

    wb.Save
    wb.Close True
  End if
Next

app.Quit
Set app = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Is it possible to save it as the new file type, but keep the original name? I am using the script you gave. Thanks a million by the way!

Comment: It's possible, but you may run into problems doing so (for instance, you can save an OpenXML workbook in the old workbook format, but trying to open that file in Excel will result in an error).

Comment: A slight change to make this script a converter from `xlsxb` to `xlsxm`: http://pastebin.com/JJbM9qRC

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, What is the meaning of the number that in the save as line?

Comment: @EsterF. They're numeric values for file format arguments. Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff841185.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Two serious bugs:

- `Set fso = Nothing` should not be inside your loop: you'll need `fso` 
  for the duration of the program.
- Also, drop `app.Quit` from the loop; keep Excel open until the very
  end.

`Set f = Nothing` is unnecessary (although benign); let the loop pick the values for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim app, fso, file, fName, wb, dir 

dir = "d:\path\"

Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each file In fso.GetFolder(dir).Files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file)) = "xlsx" Then  
    fName = fso.GetBaseName(file)

    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file) 
    app.Application.Visible = False
    app.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    app.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs dir & fName & ".xls", 43
    app.ActiveWorkbook.Close 
    app.Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
    app.Application.Quit 

    End if
Next

Set fso = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing    
Set app = Nothing

wScript.Quit
```